# IF (Condition) and (another condition) increment cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, nested, sumifs

I have two spreadsheets:

First One :

```
 **Type**   **Quantity**
  Games        1 
  Games        1
  Games        2
   DVD         1
```

Second one :

```
 **Type**   **Increment**  
    DVD
   Games
```

I want a nested IF statement in `Second one` that, if `Type` is `DVD`, will sum the corresponding `Quantity` values from `First One`, and similarly for `Games`. The expected results for my example are `1` and `4` respectively.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I want the cell increment cell to count how many times this if statement has occurred. This will be updated multiple times a day so it needs to update when the data is changed.

Comment: I think that counting dynamically will provide me with the results i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Type` is in A1 on each sheet please try:

```
=SUMIF('First One'!A:A,A2,'First One'!B:B)
```